# Text alignment on school project

Tags: html

I'm working on an HTML file for a school project. I could use some help with aligning the text on my page. I've tried display tags, such as inline-block, but nothing seems to work. The pic attached as is what I want to happen
[image]
This is what happens when I do inline-block.
[image]
Please and thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your page html?

Comment: Yup, here's the CSS https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-oE76PfeDagZ1preHpRRjBuRkE/view?usp=sharing and here's the HTML https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-oE76PfeDagM3BLUmhEVThDWk0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change you HTML code structure like this....

```
body > h1 
body > section.a > h2 > ol
body > section.b > h2 > ol
```

Now in css you have to do some changes like...

```
section.a, section.b {
  width:49%;
}

section.a{
  float:left;
}
section.b{
  float:right;
}
```

```css
body {
    /*background: url("DC.jpg") no-repeat top right;
    background-color: silver;
    background: url(MarvelDC.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  */
  background:#000;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 40;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    color: white;
}
h2, h3 {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 30;
    color: white;
}
section.b {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
section.a{
float:left;
  width:49%;

}
section.b {
float:right;
  width:49%;
}
ol.a, ol.b {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Best Marvel and DC TV Shows</h1>
<section class="a">
  
  <h2>Descriptions and Pictures</h2>
   <ol class="a">
    <li><a href="C:\Users\Nick\Documents\ECS\HTML\arrow.html">Arrow on CW: 5 Seasons, 2012-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\Users\Nick\Documents\ECS\HTML\daredevil.html">Daredevil on Netflix: 2 seasons, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\Users\Nick\Documents\ECS\HTML\agents of shield.html">Agents of SHIELD on ABC: 4 seasons, 2013-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\Users\Nick\Documents\ECS\HTML\the flash.html">The Flash on CW: 3 seasons, 2014-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="C:\Users\Nick\Documents\ECS\HTML\legends of tomorrow.html">Legends of Tomorrow on CW: 2 seasons, Jan 2016-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(TV_series)">Jessica Jones on Netflix: 1 season, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Supergirl_episodes">Supergirl on CW: 2 seasons, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage_(TV_series)">Luke Cage on Netflix: 1 season, 2016</a></li>
   </ol>
 </section>
 <section class="b">
  <h2>List of Episodes (Wiki)</h2>
   <ol class="b">
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arrow_episodes">Arrow on CW: 5 Seasons, 2012-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(TV_series)">Daredevil on Netflix: 2 seasons, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._episodes">Agents of SHIELD on ABC: 4 seasons, 2013-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Flash_episodes">The Flash on CW: 3 seasons, 2014-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_Tomorrow">Legends of Tomorrow on CW: 2 seasons, Jan 2016-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(TV_series)">Jessica Jones on Netflix: 1 season, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Supergirl_episodes">Supergirl on CW: 2 seasons, 2015-present</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage_(TV_series)">Luke Cage on Netflix: 1 season, 2016</a></li>
   </ol>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{position:relative;} 
section.b{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;}
```

Later you can change values of top & right on section.b to get it align correctly.